# Trouble getting busybox switch_root to work

Tags: busybox

I made a ext2 file system copied statically built busybox with all its softlinks. And busybox has sticky bit.(-rwsr-sr-x permissions). I have a /linuxrc and i dont have much in the /etc/ directory. And i make image from the ext2 filesystem with the following command.

```
mkimage -C gzip -A ppc -O linux -T ramdisk -a 0x2000000 -n "ramdisk" -d initrd-ext2 initrd.img
```

I keep the initrd.img as a seperate file in /boot/ and is not part of kernel.

The contents of linuxrc are

```
#!/bin/sh (Also tried #!/bin/busybox sh)

mkdir -p /proc /dev /sys /mnt /tmp
mount -t proc proc /proc
mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
mknod /dev/misc/rtc0 c 254 0
mdev -s
mkdir -p /new_root
mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /new_root
exec switch_root -c /dev/console /new_root /sbin/init
```

My kernel gets loaded properly and the initrd.img also gets loaded and the linuxrc gets executed but at the end switch_root gives usage help.

But then the my system continues to boot and loads the new rootfs. The following is the sequence.

```
RAMDISK: ext2 filesystem found at block 0
RAMDISK: Loading 10240KiB [1 disk] into ram disk... done.
VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) on device 1:0.
Starting initramfs boot...

Waiting 5 seconds for devices to settle...

kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
EXT3 FS on mmcblk0p2, internal journal
EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with writeback data mode.
BusyBox v1.21.0.git (2012-10-17 00:34:21 PDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: switch_root [-c /dev/console] NEW_ROOT NEW_INIT [ARGS]

Free initramfs and switch to another root fs:
chroot to NEW_ROOT, delete all in /, move NEW_ROOT to /,
execute NEW_INIT. PID must be 1. NEW_ROOT must be a mountpoint.

        -c DEV  Reopen stdio to DEV after switch

VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) on device 179:2.
Trying to move old root to /initrd ... /initrd does not exist. Ignored.
Unmounting old root
Trying to free ramdisk memory ... okay
Freeing unused kernel memory: 200k init
INIT: version 2.86 booting
Please wait: booting...
mount: sysfs already mounted or /sys busy
mount: according to mtab, sysfs is already mounted on /sys
Starting udev
udev: starting version 154
Root filesystem already rw, not remounting
Caching udev devnodes
```

1. Is my ram freed after exiting the initrd.img in the above sequence?
2. What if i do not do switch_root at the end of linuxrc and just put
   an exit? Wont that free up my ram from my old initrd img

.